# Flipping Fractions?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

So I'm doing summer homework for physics [Note: no previous physics knowledge required]. The prompt says solve for $t_f$. I got to here:
$$\frac{1}{t_f} = \frac{F}{-v_i(m)}$$
So I thought, why don't I just put parentheses around these two sides, and add an exponent to flip the whole thing. Right?
$$(\frac{1}{t_f})^{-1} = (\frac{F}{-v_i(m)})^{-1}$$
Which should come out to this:
$$t_f = \frac{-v_i(m)}{F}$$
I'm not sure if that works.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: That only works if and only if $F \neq 0$.

Comment: As long as you have checked that you don't have 0's in the numerators, you are okay.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Confirmed $F ≠ 0$

Comment: $a=b\implies \frac{a}{ab}=\frac{b}{ab}\implies \frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{a}\implies b^{-1}=a^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

What you did is in essence, a short cut. You could have multiplied both sides of your equality by $t_f$ then you'd have: $1=\frac{F\cdot t_f}{-v_i(m)}$.

From there, simply multiply both sides of the resulting equality by $\frac{-v_i(m)}{F}$ to get $\frac{-v_i(m)}{F}=t_f$.

And yes, like the comment's above said, you just want to avoid division by zero. (If $F=0$ this route won't work at all.)

Comment: I don't really agree that this is a shortcut. The key point is that if $x = y$, $f(x) = f(y)$, whatever the function $f$ actually is (but it has to be defined on these arguments, of course). When we "multiply both sides by a number $a$", we're applying this principle (with $f(x) = ax$), and here the OP is applying the same principle with $f(x) = x^{-1}$.

Comment: Looking at this from a completely algebraic (like high school algebra) point of view, it is a short cut. When teaching students to manipulate variables, beginning students see multiplying both sides by $t_f$ as one step, multiplying both sides by $-v_ (m)$ as one step, etc. What you describe, while perfectly valid, is not a route a took when answering this question. I explained it in the same way I would to students struggling with algebraic manipulation. (In the hopes of making seemingly simple concepts simple to grasp.)

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with you that different people need different explanations. But I do think that explaining quite early to students that the recipes they learn to solve equations are justified by things like "if two things are equal, then they remain equal if we apply the same treatment to them" is a good idea (and I took this occasion to insist on this principle, I didn't mean the comment as a criticism).